# Delete URLs with specific domains from MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have URLs in column URL. I would like to delete all URLs from database with selected domains. In database are different domains. Do I need to use regex?
For example, I have urls:

```
https://example.com/something/gnsgngdf
https://example.com/?%jgfingi
https://anotherdomain.net/?gdtfhj65
etc.
```

I would like to write one SQL expression to delete all URLs that begin with selected domain. Something like this:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE url = regex: https://example.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you could use a simple `like`

```
 DELETE FROM table WHERE url  liKe 'https://example.com%'
```

Comment: It doesnt work, but I dont know why. I use SQLite, maybe this?

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE url like 'https://example.com%'
```

do not forget the `%`

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE url like 'https://example.com%'
```

No need for a regex. You can use the like operator. Now everything is deleted which starts with this URL.

See [detailed explanation](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

Comment: It should work. Did you spell the url correctly? And change the mysql tag in your question please.